# Exercise about of the closure of an Set

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,B$ and $A_{\alpha}$ denote subsets of a space $X$. Determine whether the following equations hold. If an equality fails, determine whether one of the inclusions $\subset$ or $\supset$ holds.

a) $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$

b) $\overline{\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}}=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} \overline{A}_{\alpha}$

c) $\overline{A\setminus B}=\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}$

Hello! The part a) I have solved, but my question is about of the part b) and c). I think that can take any element for showed, but isn't clear see how this is an result. Thanks.

Comment: About of the part a) we have that $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$ and $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \subset \overline{A\cap B}$. At have double inclusion the result it follow.

Comment: There's no equality in (a): consider the usual topology on $\mathbb R$. Then $$\overline{(0, 1) \cap (1, 2)} = \overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset$$ but $$\overline{(1,2)} \cap \overline{(1,2)} = [0, 1] \cap [1, 2] = \{ 1 \} \ne \emptyset.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality does not hold in (b). To show that $\subset$ holds, consider $x\in\overline{\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha}.$ It is in every closed set that contains $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$. So what does that say about closed sets containing $A_\alpha$ for some particular $\alpha$?

Equality also doesn't hold for (c). To show that $\supset$ holds, consider $x\in\overline A\cap \setminus\overline B$. Every closed set containing $A$ contains $x$, but there is a closed set containing $B$ which does not contain $x$. This means that $x$ is not contained in $B$. So what does that say about every closed set that contains $A\setminus B$?